# What is difference between official Magento 2 and github Magento2?

Tags: magento2

Because when I see offical Magento2 there is no Core in the the `app/code` but when you see in the github there is Core Code `app/code/Magento`

Comment: What do you mean by official Magento 2 ?

Comment: Magento 2 system is smart enough to read your code either from app/code/<Vendor> or vendor/<package>, in fact the magic happens with the registration.php + composer.json

Comment: @ Raphael If you download Magento 2 from official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version from github is addressed to contributors.
It is easier for contributors to clone a repo and create pull requests.
For the downloadable version, the modules that should be in `app/code` are retrieved via composer and are placed in `vendor` folder.
The downloadable version is suited for production.